# Partial function explanation in the Odersky book

Tags: scala, partial-functions

In the Scala Odersky book, he has an example explaining partial functions of page 295. It starts with this function:

```
val second: List[Int] => Int = {
    case x :: y :: _ => y
}
```

So the above function will succeed if you pass it a three element list but not an empty list.

```
second(List(5,6,7))
```

works but not

```
second(List())
```

The above will throw a `MatchError: List`

Here is the part that is confusing to me. Odersky writes:

> If you want to check whether a partial function is defined, you must first tell the compiler that you know you are working with partial functions.

Why would I want to check whether a partial function is defined. What is a partial function? Is it a function that only applies to some values?

> The type List[Int] => Int includes all functions from lists of integers to integers, whether or not the functions are partial. The type that only includes partial functions from lists of integers to integers is written PartialFunction[List[Int], Int].

So the above function returns a function of type List[Int] => Int, I see that, but why do we need to change this function to type `PartialFunction[List[Int], Int]`?

Here is the function redefined:

```
val second: PartialFunction[List [Int], Int] = {
    case x :: y :: _ => y
}
```

I don't really get it. What is the benefit? Why do we want to check whether a partial function is defined? What does that even mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *partial function* is any function, which takes only a single argument, that is *defined* (i.e. valid) only for a certain range of its argument's values. For example, `Math.asin` is defined only for argument values in the range `[-1.0, 1.0]` and is undefined for values outside of that range - so it is a partial function. For example, if we call `Math.asin(5.0)`, we get `NaN` returned, meaning that the function is not defined for that argument.

Note that a partial function doesn't necessarily have to throw an exception; it just needs to do something other than return a valid value.

A key principle of *functional programming* is *referential transparency* (*RT*), meaning that we should be able to replace an expression (such as a function call) with the value of that expression, without changing the meaning of the program. (For more on this topic, I highly recommend that you read [*Functional Programming in Scala*](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) by Chiusano and Bjarnason.) Clearly, that breaks down if an exception is thrown or if an invalid value is returned. For calls to partial functions to be referentially transparent, we can only call them with argument values for which they are defined, or we need to elegantly handle the undefined values. So how can we tell if a partial function is defined for some arbitrary argument value?

In *Scala* we can express partial functions as a subclass of [`scala.PartialFunction`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html) that allows us to answer this question.

Let's look at your example in a *Scala REPL* session...

```scala
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_171).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val second: List[Int] => Int = {
     |     case x :: y :: _ => y
     | }
<console>:11: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: List(_), Nil
       val second: List[Int] => Int = {
                                  ^
second: List[Int] => Int = $$Lambda$3181/1894473818@27492c62
```

So what did we just do? We defined `second` as a reference to a function that takes a `List[Int]` argument and returns an `Int` (the second value in the list).

You'll notice that the *Scala compiler* recognizes that this is not going to match all cases and warns you of the fact. This is a partial function, in the sense that it will fail for some arguments, but it's not an instance of `scala.PartialFunction`, as we can verify as follows:

```scala
scala> second.isInstanceOf[PartialFunction[List[Int], Int]]
res0: Boolean = false
```

Incidentally, the type `List[Int] => Int` is a shorthand for `scala.Function1[List[Int], Int]` and so `second`s type is an instance of that type:

```scala
scala> second.isInstanceOf[Function1[List[Int], Int]]
res1: Boolean = true
```

Calling this version of the function produces the results you indicate:

```scala
scala> second(List(1, 2, 3))
res1: Int = 2

scala> second(Nil)
scala.MatchError: List() (of class scala.collection.immutable.Nil$)
  at .$anonfun$second$1(<console>:11)
  at .$anonfun$second$1$adapted(<console>:11)
  ... 36 elided
```

The problem is that if we just have some list value, `l`, and don't know what is in that list, we don't know whether we'll get an exception if we pass it to the function referenced by `second`. Now, we could put the call in a `try` block and `catch` any exception, but that's verbose and not good *functional programming style*. Ideally, we'd like to know whether we can call the function first to avoid an exception. Unfortunately, there's no way to tell from a `Function1` instance:

```scala
scala> second.isDefinedAt(Nil)
<console>:13: error: value isDefinedAt is not a member of List[Int] => Int
       second.isDefinedAt(Nil)
              ^
```

What we need is to declare `second` to have the type `PartialFunction[List[Int], Int]` as follows:

```scala
scala> val second: PartialFunction[List[Int], Int] = {
     |   case x :: y :: _ => y
     | }
second: PartialFunction[List[Int],Int] = <function1>
```

(BTW, note that you have a typo in your question for this code - the above is how this should be defined.)

Now we do not have any warnings! We've told the compiler that this is a `PartialFunction` instance, so the compiler knows that its undefined for some arguments, so warnings are superfluous. We can now verify that fact:

```scala
scala> second.isInstanceOf[PartialFunction[List[Int], Int]]
res6: Boolean = true
```

We can now also verify whether it's defined for particular values:

```scala
scala> second.isDefinedAt(Nil)
res7: Boolean = false

scala> second.isDefinedAt(List(1, 2))
res9: Boolean = true
```

and so on. (The *Scala* compiler, as described in the book, is able to implement this magical `isDefinedAt` function for us.)

So, does that mean we should now write code like this:

```scala
def getSecondValue(l: List[Int]): Option[Int] = {

  // Check if second is defined for this argument. If so, call it and wrap in Some.
  if(second.isDefinedAt(l)) Some(second(l))

  // Otherwise, we do not have a second value.
  else None
}
```

Well, that's a little verbose too. Fortunately, once `second` is a `PartialFunction` instance, we can rewrite the above as:

```scala
def getSecondValue(l: List[Int]): Option[Int] = second.lift(l)
```

The `lift` method turns a partial function into a *complete function* that returns a defined value for every argument: if the argument to `second` is defined, then we get a `Some(value)`; otherwise, we get `None`.

You'll find the concept of partial functions, and `PartialFunction`, more useful as you become more familiar with *functional programming*. If you don't *get it* right now, don't worry; all will become clear.

Answer (score 0):

A partial function is a function that does not provide an answer for every possible input value it can be given. It provides an answer only for a subset of possible data, and defines the data it can handle. In Scala, a partial function can also be queried to determine if it can handle a particular value.
As a simple example, imagine a normal function that divides one number by another:

```
val divide = (x: Int) => 42 / x
```

As defined, this function blows up when the input parameter is zero:

```
scala> divide(0)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Although you can handle this particular situation by catching and throwing an exception, Scala lets you define the divide function as a PartialFunction. When doing so, you also explicitly state that the function is defined when the input parameter is not zero:

```
val divide = new PartialFunction[Int, Int] {
def apply(x: Int) = 42 / x
def isDefinedAt(x: Int) = x != 0
}
```

> https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-use-partial-functions-in-scala-syntax-examples

You can refer to the above link.